# How to interpret the calculation of the confidence interval for a Cox-Ingersoll-Ross process?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, stochastic-processes

I need to interpret the calculation of the confidence interval (CI) for the [Cox-Ingersoll-Ross (CIR) proсess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model).

From the paper ([Nafidi et. al., 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15678)) we know that
transition probability is $p(t, y|s, x) \sim \zeta \chi^2_k(\lambda) $, with degrees of freedom
$k = \frac{4}{\sigma^2} \theta \beta$,
$\zeta  =  \frac{\sigma^2}{4} \frac{1-e^{-\theta(t-s)}}{\theta}$
and non-centrality parameter
$\lambda = \frac{4 \theta e^{-\theta(t-s)}}{\sigma^2(1-e^{-\theta(t-s)})}x_s$.

Let us denote $v(s, t) = p(t, y|s, x) = x_s$. Therefore, the random variable
$$
\frac{v(s,t)}{\zeta} \sim \chi^2_k(\lambda).$$

We make the approximation of the chi-square by
the standard normal distribution. So, the random
variable $z$ is given by
$$
z = \frac{\frac{v(s,t)}{\zeta} - (k + \lambda)}{\sqrt{2(k + 2\lambda)}} \sim 
N(0, 1), \quad \text{when } k \rightarrow \infty \text{ or } \lambda \rightarrow \infty.
$$
A $100(1 - \alpha)\%$ conditional confidence interval for $z$ is
given by $$P(-\xi \leq z \leq  \xi) = 1 - \alpha.$$ From this, we can
obtain a confidence interval of $v(s, t)$ with following form
\begin{equation}\label{CI_CIR}
(v_{lower}(s, t), v_{upper}(s, t))  = \zeta (k + \lambda \pm \xi \sqrt{2(k + 2\lambda)})
\end{equation}
with $\xi = \Phi^{-1}_{N(0,1)}(1 - \alpha/2)$.

I have made the calculation for CIR process $x_0 = 10$, parameters
$\theta = (2., 0.2, 0.15)$ and obtained the CI with $\alpha = 0.05$. The results is in figure below.

[image]

**Question.** Is it possible to define the CI from one path or not? How one can to interpret the result?

Comment: Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange might be another suitable site for this question.